# Linq. Select contains any of array char

Tags: linq

My data is such as

```
A12
12B
333
CC4
```

How can i select the records provided from a char array?

```
var c = new char[] {'A','B','C'};
```

Something like the following

```
var result = context.data.Where(x => x.SerialNo.Contains(c)).ToList();
```

In the test case above the result should be equal to

```
A12
12B
CC4
```

since `A` is available in first line, `B` on second and `C` on the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = context.data
    .Where(x => x.SerialNo.Any(l => c.Contains(l)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hello, i get cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<char, bool>'

Comment: @OrElse weird, thought it would convert,  changed it

Comment: You are right. Had typo in array declaration var c = new char[] {} Just edited to array of chars